# Basic Regular Expression matching in VIM

Tags: regex, vim

what would be the value that will match this?

```
'\(x\)\(y\)z\2\1'
```

I thought that it would be word xyz but it's not working?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

That should match `xyzyx` ...

You're creating capture groups for `x` and `y` and referencing those with `\2` (`y`) and `\1` (`x`) respectively.